# How to changing the x symbol in a foundation 4 custom checkbox

Tags: css, html, mobile, sass, compass-sass

I am looking for a way to override the checked (x) style in a foundation for custom checkbox

Following the custom [forms documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/custom-forms.html) I have successfully implemented a custom checkbox as follows:

```
<form class="custom">
    <label for="checkbox1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" CHECKED />
        <span class="custom checkbox checked"></span>Label for checkbox 1
    </label>
</form>
```

This allows me to make css style changes to the look of the checkbox, but I can't find a way te effect the x itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look in the [CSS file](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/assets/docs.css) used on the page you link to, you will find this part, that is styling the checked checkbox:

```
form.custom .custom.checkbox.checked:before {
    content: "\00d7";
    color: #222222;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

changing the content will change the symbol displayed. Hope this helps.

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/uzobih/3/edit) (provided in Andrey's comment)

Comment: thanks @Andrey'lolmaus'Mikhaylov, I added a link to your demo directly into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

change the value of content in your css

```
form.custom .custom.checkbox.checked:before {
content: "×00d7";}
```

to

```
 form.custom .custom.checkbox.checked:before {
    content: "*";}
```

or what ever you want

Answer (score 1):

Try this code which would change the "x" to true sign

```
form.custom .custom.checkbox.checked:before {
content: "\2714";}
```